# app widget is not being updated after first automatic onUpdate is called

Tags: android, kotlin, widget, appwidgetprovider, onupdate

I experienced some change in the behaviour of my widget:

Previously the widget was updating automatically (every 30min) and after some certain widget action has happened (after a new entry had been added to some database). Also after some automatic update, the widget was still updating after the widget action was triggered. (so far the expected behavior)

Now after the first automatic (onUpdate) has happend, the widget action does not update the text of the textview anymore.
Before the first automatic update, the widget action does still change the text of the textview.
While debugging the onUpdate method of the AppWidgetProvider, a new value had been calculated and is set to the text of the textview, but the widget is still showing the old value.

Except this widget action, all other widget actions are still working fine. So the widget has not been destroyed by some error or so.

Like I said in the past this was working totally fine and I didn't apply any major changes in the widget logic (just some rounding things for the textview)...

How did I got this suspicion:
I added some vibration action into the onUpdate method so that I know when the first automatic update has taken place. After the first vibration the widget action does not update the textview anymore...

Android 13, July Update
Pixel 7 and Pixel 5